# Transformar resultado JSON para 'uppercase'

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON (completo):

```
{
  "name": "Romano Pesca",
  "count": 8,
  "frequency": "Weekly",
  "version": 5,
  "newdata": false,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "thisversionstatus": "success",
  "nextrun": "Sat Aug 08 2015 15:14:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "thisversionrun": "Sat Aug 01 2015 15:14:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "img": {
          "alt": "Vara Sumax Victória 9'0\" ( 2,70m ) Para Carretilha",
          "href": "http://www.romanopesca.com.br/vara-sumax-victoria-9-0-2-70m-para-carretilha.php",
          "src": "http://www.romanopesca.com.br/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/u/sumax-080357_1.jpg",
          "text": ""
        },
        "prod": {
          "href": "http://www.romanopesca.com.br/vara-sumax-victoria-9-0-2-70m-para-carretilha.php",
          "text": "Vara Sumax Victória 9'0\" ( 2,70m ) Para Carretilha"
        },
        "valor": "R$242,91",
        "index": 1,
        "url": "http://www.romanopesca.com.br/"
      },
```

Preciso colocar os valores que está dentro das chaves "prod" -> "text" em letra MAIÚSCULA.

```
    "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "prod": {
          "text": "ARA SUMAX VICTÓRIA 9'0" ( 2,70M ) PARA CARRETILHA"
        },
```

Tenho o seguinte código, para casos em php:

```
    <?php
$request ="https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7fzc196k?apikey=9TCUO9EskMyL4HtmqHMNDIiaZ9KmOcXn";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response, TRUE);
array_walk_recursive($results, function ($value)
{
   $value = mb_strtoupper($value, 'UTF-8');
});

$meu_json_tudo_maiusculo = json_encode($results);

?>
```

Pensei também em usar uma função em javascript, no lugar do php, para alterar o resultado do JSON, deixando-o maiúsculo.

Até agora não está funcionando o código acima.

Comment: vc qquer as chaves do array em maiusculas ou so o valor?

Comment: só o valor, @rray

Comment: Você precisa somente apresentar esses valores em uppercase numa página web?

Comment: @rocmartins não, eu preciso transformar o JSON em uppercase. É para efeitos de busca no site.

Comment: Nesse caso, acredito que a aproximação mais correta seja fazer uma busca que seja case insensitive.

Comment: @rocmartins tem algum material para me enviar?

Comment: Consegui usando 'stristr' no lugar de 'strto'.  Ficou asism: if(stristr($collection['prod']['text'],$string) !== false) {

                echo...

Comment: @GustavoCave depende muito de como está fazendo a busca. Não entendi qual a estrutura da busca e pra que precisa do JSON.

Comment: Seu JSON ainda continua errado! Está faltando o fechamento com `]` e `} `

Answer (score 2):

Vou deixar minha resposta no caso de fazer isso em PHP.

```
$array =  json_decode($meu_json, true);

array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value)
{
   $value = mb_strtoupper($value, 'UTF-8');
});

print_r($array);
```

Para converter novamente pra json

```
$meu_json_tudo_maiusculo = json_encode($array);
```

## ATUALIZAÇÃO

Visto que você copiou minha resposta para colocá-la na sua pergunta, gostaria de frisar que você não está usando o operador de referência  `&` e talvez seja por isso que não está funcionando!

Outra observação: Seu JSON está mal formado.

Veja nesse exemplo que, o meu JSON estando corretamente formado, funciona.

http://ideone.com/cYx6Zh

Quando o JSON está mal formado, ele retorna `false` ao usar `json_decode`.
Talvez seja o caso de você verificar se isso está acontecendo com seu código.

Considerando também que foram relatados problemas em relação ao link da imagem, você pode simplesmente ignorar as urls na transformação do conteúdo do json.

Então o código ficará assim:

```
$array =  json_decode($meu_json, true);

array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value)
{
   if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) return;

   $value = mb_strtoupper($value, 'UTF-8');
});

print_r($array);
```

Veja esse exemplo no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/tUUDdz)

Comment: estou trabalhando nesse código que me enviou, por enquanto sem resultados.

Comment: `$meu_json` deve ser a string do JSON. Lembrando que o seu json está mal formado (se puder colocar ele completo na pergunta)

Comment: editei a pergunta.

Comment: Tem um erro no seu código. Você não colocou o `&`  no parâmetro!

Comment: Coloquei e não deu certo.

Comment: Tentei assim também @Wallace Maxters , mas não deu certo. $upper = array($collection['prod']['text']);
return(array_change_key_case($upper,CASE_UPPER));

Comment: consegui fazer funcionar o jeito que você disse, porém as imagens sumiram. Código: array_walk_recursive($results, function (&$value)
{
   $value = mb_strtoupper($value, 'UTF-8');
});
$meu_json_tudo_maiusculo = json_encode($results);